# How to "wrap" rows and column indicies around?

Tags: python

I want to be able to "wrap" around the matrix when it reaches the end of the matrix, row, and column-wise.

My current code reads a matrix from a file and finds all the `'.'` into a list of row coordinates and column coordinates.

I want to check the neighboring indices to see if they are `'O'`.

```
for x in range(0, len(row_dead)):
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] - 1][column_dead[x]]) == 'O':  # above
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] + 1][column_dead[x]]) == 'O':  # below
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x]][column_dead[x] + 1]) == 'O':  # right
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x]][column_dead[x] - 1]) == 'O':  # left
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] - 1][column_dead[x] + 1]) == 'O':  # up_right
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] - 1][column_dead[x] - 1]) == 'O':  # up_left
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] + 1][column_dead[x] + 1]) == 'O':  # bot_right
        count += 1
    if (content_matrix[row_dead[x] + 1][column_dead[x] - 1]) == 'O':  # bot_left
        count += 1
```

The code I have works fine when the `'.'` is not bordering the perimeter of the matrix. However, if there is a `'.'` on the perimeter of the matrix, I get an index out of range error.

I do have a solution in my head and it's to hard code every indices along the parameter to "wrap" around to certain indices, but I feel like that way is too primitive and I feel like there's a way to properly wrap around the indices mathematically.

Comment: can you paste the code to generate your `content_matrix` or the matrix itself if its small?

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator to wrap your subscript around either end.  I'll use shorter variable names: given a 2D structure `grid` with indices `row` and `col`:

```
grid[ (col+1) % len(grid) ]
       [ (row-1) % len(grid[0]) ]
```

This assumes that `len(grid[0])` gives you the column quantity (row length) for any column -- otherwise, you'd have to specify the same index you used for the col.

For instance, give a 5x5 grid, `4+1 % 5` will return `0`; `0-1 % 5` will return `4`.

Does that get you going?

Answer (score 0):

Use `try`/`except` statements

There should be smarter and more pythonic ways to do this but this should work:

```py
for x in range(0, len(row_dead)):
    xx = row_dead[x]
    yy = column_dead[x]
    for ox, oy in [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]:
        try:
            count += content_matrix[xx+ox][yy+oy] == 'O'  # Ugly but works
        except IndexError:
            pass
```